# how to configure log4j rolling file appender in SpringBoot application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

I'm working on spring boot application. For logging I'm trying to use log4j. Can anyone help me to configure the RollingFileAppender in application.yml

I have following log4j dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Currently I'm try with following code:

```
log4j.appender.File: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.File.file: ${basedir}/logs
log4j.appender.File.rollingPolicy: org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.File.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern: %d{ddMMyyyy}.log
```

I want to store the log file in the project itself and the file pattern should DD-MM-YYYY.log.
And also in my function, I'm printing my log as follows :

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingFile.class);
logger.info("Printing logs in file");
```

I can able to see this in console, but the file is not creating. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using? Spring Boot dropped Log4j 1.2 support in the 1.4.x series. Log4j 2.x is supported (but your configuration is for Log4j 1.2), but it is **not** the default logging backend.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz My spring boot version is 2.5.5. So I have changed the log4j version to 2.11.1. But still it's not working

Comment: This is not relevant to issue, but hopefully you have read about [log4j security vulnerability](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html), since it is the most talked about thing in software engineering nowadays. Check if your version is among those that needs fixing.

Comment: @Susmitha: there are many things wrong with your configuration. You should read [chapter 4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging) of Spring Boot's documentation (especially 4.3 and 4.7). Basically in the `application.yml` file you have a very limited amount of logging configuration. If you want more, you need to use a native `log4j2-spring.xml` file (your configuration is not compatible with Log4j 2.x; it is only valid for Log4j 1.2).

Answer (score 0):

I think LogBack is a better choice, the following is the relevant configuration

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds">
<contextName>heron</contextName>
<property name="appName" value="adminLte"/>
<property name="logPath" value="/tmp/logs"/>

<!--控制台日志-->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{16} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!--基于时间和文件尺寸的轮转-->
<appender name="rollingFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${logPath}/${appName}/${appName}.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${logPath}/${appName}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/${appName}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>15</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>5GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{16} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="website.lhc" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="rollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>


<logger name="org.springframework.security" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="rollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>


<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="rollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
```